Checkbox it's not working with the mandatory in DocuSign using REST APIs
Checkbox it's not working with the mandatory in DocuSign using REST APIs
I'm trying to mark a checkbox as mandatory, but I can't. I'm trying to send but the fields are coming as optional. I've already tried using the examples in:
https://apirequestbuilder.docusign.com/
however, he was unsuccessful.what am I doing wrong?
I added the Groups tab
a part of my JSON:
  tabs: class Tabs {
                approveTabs: null
                checkboxTabs: [class Checkbox {
                    anchorAllowWhiteSpaceInCharacters: null
                    anchorAllowWhiteSpaceInCharactersMetadata: null
                    anchorCaseSensitive: null
                    anchorCaseSensitiveMetadata: null
                    anchorHorizontalAlignment: null
                    anchorHorizontalAlignmentMetadata: null
                    anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent: true
                    anchorIgnoreIfNotPresentMetadata: null
                    anchorMatchWholeWord: null
                    anchorMatchWholeWordMetadata: null
                    anchorString: /cbx_1_1/
                    anchorStringMetadata: null
                    anchorTabProcessorVersion: null
                    anchorTabProcessorVersionMetadata: null
                    anchorUnits: pixels
                    anchorUnitsMetadata: null
                    anchorYOffset: null
                    anchorYOffsetMetadata: null
                    boldMetadata: null
                    conditionalParentLabel: null
                    conditionalParentLabelMetadata: null
                    conditionalParentValue: on
                    conditionalParentValueMetadata: null
                    customTabId: null
                    customTabIdMetadata: null
                    documentId: 1
                    mergeFieldXml: null
                    name: Salario Pro/Labore
                    nameMetadata: null
                    originalValue: null
                    pageNumber: null
                    pageNumberMetadata: null
                    recipientId: 1
                    recipientIdGuid: null
                    recipientIdGuidMetadata: null
                    recipientIdMetadata: null
                    required: null
                    requiredMetadata: null
                    requireInitialOnSharedChange: null
                    requireInitialOnSharedChangeMetadata: null
                    selected: false
                    selectedMetadata: null
                    source: null
                    status: null
                    statusMetadata: null
                    tabGroupLabels: [checkbox group]
                    tabGroupLabelsMetadata: null
                    tabId: /cbx_1_1/
                    tabIdMetadata: null
                    tabLabel: Salario Pro/Labore
                }

my tabgrop:

    tabGroups: [class TabGroup {
                        anchorAllowWhiteSpaceInCharacters: null
                        anchorAllowWhiteSpaceInCharactersMetadata: null
                        anchorCaseSensitive: null
                        anchorCaseSensitiveMetadata: null
                        anchorHorizontalAlignment: null
                        anchorHorizontalAlignmentMetadata: null
                        anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent: null
                        anchorIgnoreIfNotPresentMetadata: null
                        anchorMatchWholeWord: null
                        anchorMatchWholeWordMetadata: null
                        anchorString: null
                        anchorStringMetadata: null
                        anchorTabProcessorVersion: null
                        anchorTabProcessorVersionMetadata: null
                        anchorUnits: null
                        anchorUnitsMetadata: null
                        anchorXOffset: null
                        anchorXOffsetMetadata: null
                        anchorYOffset: null
                        anchorYOffsetMetadata: null
                        conditionalParentLabel: null
                        conditionalParentLabelMetadata: null
                        conditionalParentValue: null
                        conditionalParentValueMetadata: null
                        customTabId: null
                        customTabIdMetadata: null
                        documentId: null
                        documentIdMetadata: null
                        errorDetails: null
                        formOrder: null
                        formOrderMetadata: null
                        formPageLabel: null
                        formPageLabelMetadata: null
                        formPageNumber: null
                        formPageNumberMetadata: null
                        groupLabel: checkbox group
                        groupLabelMetadata: null
                        groupRule: SelectAtLeast
                        groupRuleMetadata: null
                        height: null
                        heightMetadata: null
                        maximumAllowed: 50
                        maximumAllowedMetadata: null
                        mergeField: null
                        mergeFieldXml: null
                        minimumRequired: 50
                        minimumRequiredMetadata: null
                        pageNumber: null
                        pageNumberMetadata: null
                        recipientId: null
                        recipientIdGuid: null
                        recipientIdGuidMetadata: null
                        recipientIdMetadata: null
                        smartContractInformation: null
                        source: null
                        status: null
                        statusMetadata: null
                        tabGroupLabels: null
                        tabGroupLabelsMetadata: null
                        tabId: null
                        tabIdMetadata: null
                        tabOrder: null
                        tabOrderMetadata: null
                        tabScope: document
                        tabScopeMetadata: null
                        tabType: null
                        tabTypeMetadata: null
                        templateLocked: null
                        templateLockedMetadata: null
                        templateRequired: null
                        templateRequiredMetadata: null
                        tooltip: null
                        toolTipMetadata: null
                        validationMessage: Please check to indicate your agreement
                        validationMessageMetadata: null
                        width: null
                        widthMetadata: null
                        xPosition: null
                        xPositionMetadata: null
                        yPosition: null
                        yPositionMetadata: null

Java ---
call my method:
  List<Tabs> tabs = this.getCheckbox(numProposta, rs.getString("seq_envelope"));
            for(Tabs t : tabs ){
                signerTabs.setCheckboxTabs(t.getCheckboxTabs());
                signerTabs.setTabGroups(t.getTabGroups());
            }



    private List<Tabs> getCheckbox(String numProposta, String seq_envelope) throws Exception {
    String GET_CHECKBOXES =
            "SELECT eac.cd_envelope, " +
                    "       eac.seq_envelope, " +
                    "       eac.seq_arq_env, " +
                    "       eac.tag, " +
                    "       eac.ds_valor, " +
                    "       eac.cd_arquivo, " +
                    "       eac.cd_checkbox, " +
                    "       eac.is_checked " +
                    "  FROM envelope_assinatura_checkbox eac " +
                    " WHERE eac.cd_envelope = ? " +
                    "   AND eac.seq_envelope = ? ";

    PreparedStatement ps = connection.getConnection().prepareStatement(GET_CHECKBOXES);
    List<Checkbox> checkboxList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> tabGroupLabels1 = Arrays.asList("checkbox");
    List<TabGroup> tabGroups = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Tabs> tabsList = new ArrayList<>();

    ps.setString(1, numProposta);
    ps.setString(2, seq_envelope);
    ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()) {
        Checkbox checkboxTab1 = new Checkbox();
        checkboxTab1.setAnchorString(rs.getString("tag").trim());
        checkboxTab1.setName(rs.getString("ds_valor"));
        checkboxTab1.setRecipientId(rs.getString("seq_envelope"));
        checkboxTab1.setTabLabel(rs.getString("ds_valor"));
        checkboxTab1.setTabId(rs.getString("tag").trim());
        checkboxTab1.setSelected(rs.getBoolean("is_checked") ? "true" : "false");
        checkboxTab1.setRequired("true");  // Tornando o checkbox obrigatório
        checkboxTab1.setAnchorUnits("pixels");
        checkboxTab1.setAnchorIgnoreIfNotPresent("true");
        checkboxTab1.documentId(rs.getString("seq_envelope"));
        checkboxTab1.setTabGroupLabels(tabGroupLabels1);
        checkboxList.add(checkboxTab1);
    }

    TabGroup tabGroup1 = new TabGroup();
    tabGroup1.setGroupLabel("checkbox");
    tabGroup1.setGroupRule("SelectAtLeast");
    tabGroup1.setMinimumRequired("1"); // Requer pelo menos 1 checkbox selecionado
    tabGroup1.setMaximumAllowed("1"); // Limita a 1 checkbox selecionado
    tabGroup1.tabScope("document");
    tabGroup1.setValidationMessage("Por favor, selecione pelo menos um checkbox.");

    tabGroups.add(tabGroup1);
    Tabs tabs = new Tabs();
    tabs.setCheckboxTabs(checkboxList);
    tabs.setTabGroups(tabGroups);
    tabsList.add(tabs);
    return tabsList;
}


required: null I see in there, should be "true"

Here is an example of JSON to create a group of two checkboxes that are required.
{
    "checkboxTabs": [
        {
            "tabLabel": "Checkbox12345",
            "conditionalParentLabel": null,
            "conditionalParentValue": null,
            "isPrefilledTab": false,
            "agreementAttribute": "",
            "agreementAttributeLocked": false,
            "fontSize": "size9",
            "underline": false,
            "italic": false,
            "fontColor": "black",
            "bold": false,
            "font": "lucidaconsole",
            "locked": false,
            "name": "",
            "required": true,
            "selected": false,
            "shared": false,
            "shareToRecipients": "",
            "recipientId": "56764645",
            "pageNumber": 1,
            "documentId": "1",
            "tabGroupLabels": [
                "Checkbox Group 1234567"
            ],
            "xPosition": 108,
            "yPosition": 219,
            "width": 0,
            "height": 0,
            "trackingId": "c291",
            "trackingid": "c291"
        },
        {
            "tabLabel": "Checkbox 1234566",
            "conditionalParentLabel": null,
            "conditionalParentValue": null,
            "isPrefilledTab": false,
            "agreementAttribute": "",
            "agreementAttributeLocked": false,
            "fontSize": "size9",
            "underline": false,
            "italic": false,
            "fontColor": "black",
            "bold": false,
            "font": "lucidaconsole",
            "locked": false,
            "required": true,
            "shared": false,
            "shareToRecipients": "",
            "recipientId": "56764645",
            "pageNumber": 1,
            "documentId": "1",
            "tabGroupLabels": [
                "Checkbox Group 1234567"
            ],
            "xPosition": 108,
            "yPosition": 235,
            "width": 0,
            "height": 0,
            "trackingId": "c311",
            "trackingid": "c311"
        }
    ]
}


Inbar, Did you leave out the Checkbox Group definition?

oops, let me fix, I had the wrong tabGroupLabels, that's what groups them together

Do you have any example in Java? it would help me a lot

You didn't share Java code Igor, can you share your code and I can try to help if it's not working

@InbarGazit I edited my question with the Java code, thanks for the help.

So what is the issue with this code? does it not work at all?

@InbarGazit the boxes continue to be optional.

ok, not sure what does it mean a required checkbox. A checkbox that is either checked or unchecked, only two options. If it's unchecked, it was still filled, by deciding not to check it. Do you want to force it to be checked?
